# How to require vendor/autoload.php with behat.yml

Tags: composer-php, behat

In my project I have an `autoload.php` file which is responsible for requiring *context* classes. This is the file auto-generated by Composer. How can I include that file using `behat.yml`?

In PHPUnit's `phpunit.xml.dist` I can do this simply with `bootstrap` attribute like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
```

Is there a similar setting in Behat?

**Note**: I'm not asking about running Behat from `vendor` directory, because when I do it works as expected. That's because the file `vendor/bin/behat` contains the

```
include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

expression. But I also have `behat` installed globally and when I run global `behat` command it fails to autoload my context classes. And this is the use case that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer's autoloader is used by default.

However, depending on where you've installed Behat a different autoloader will be used. Project's autoloader is used if you installed Behat in your project, while the global autoloader is used if you installed Behat globally.

There's no way of changing this behaviour with configuration alone. Note that this is an expected behaviour. See https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/490#issuecomment-40928786

Furthermore, installing Behat in your project is the recommended way.

You could probably write a Behat extension to include project's autoloader even if a global behat version is used, but I don't think it's worth it. It could also lead to odd autoloading issues with duplicate or wrong versions of classes etc.

Finally, you can also configure the autoloader manually: http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/6.profiles.html#custom-autoloading

Comment: This makes sense, but I still would like to have the option to bootstrap my test project. If not for autoloading purposes then for defining constants, importing services etc. [Behat 1.0 had support for bootstrap.php file](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/migrate_from_1x_to_20.html#migrating-bootstrap-scripts) and I can't imagine why it was dropped. The suggested solution is to do this now in context files. This is IMO a very dirty workaround, not a solution.

Comment: But you gave me an idea for a cleaner solution. I'll write something like an extension (or at least a runner with bootstrap) for Behat when I find some time.

Comment: One of the first things I do when bootstrapping a project is to run `composer init`. This will bring tools like behat in, and I can use them to bootstrap features/specs/etc. I really see no point of installing behat globally. It's also not the recommended way of installing it.

Comment: Yes, we agreed on that. But the question remains how to bootstrap the the behat run for that specific project. Eg. where to put things like `define('MY_PROJECT_FIXTURES_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../fixtures');`

Comment: How about configuring it In behat.yml? If you need to make it a constant, it could be done in context's constructor, or with a custom extension. It used to be that behat loaded everything from features/bootstrap/ automatically. Might be it still does, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following new BehatExtension:

https://github.com/Postcon/BehatBootstrapExtension